# Add search to MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote MySQL query, it returns results from two tables related to particular user ID (in live project each user sees own data). What I am trying to achieve is to insert search option, but can't find proper way to do it. Search should work with columns: object, name, color and age. Key which connects two tables is 'object'. Thanks if someone could point me to the right direction.

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table1.object, table2.name, table2.object, table2.color, table2.age
    FROM table2
    JOIN table1 ON table2.object = table1.object 
    WHERE (table1.user_id = '".$user['id']."')
    ORDER BY table1.object ASC
```

Comment: please add table structure and a sample of expected outcome

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a string value anywhere in the field:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE field1 LIKE '%VALUE%';
```

If you are looking for an exact match:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE field1 = 'VALUE';
```

Comment: But there are several other conditions, like return result according to user_id and later allow to search between those results.

Comment: You can put those additional conditions in your WHERE clause.

Example:

SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE field1 = 'VALUE' AND field2=1;

Answer (score 0):

Bryan's answer is correct.  You can either filter out in the original query or you can also filter out after the join.

```
SELECT table1.user_id, table1.object, table2.name, table2.object, table2.color, table2.age
FROM table2
JOIN table1 ON table2.object = table1.object 
WHERE (table1.user_id = '".$user['id']."') and table2.color='red' and 'table2.age=15 
ORDER BY table1.object ASC
```

If you want to return the joined results and then search, you can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT table1.user_id, table1.object as obj1, table2.name, table2.object, table2.color, table2.age
    FROM table2
    JOIN table1 ON table2.object = table1.object 
    WHERE (table1.user_id = '".$user['id']."'))tblA WHERE color='red' and age=15
    ORDER BY obj1
```